# cartesian product of arrays in dask

Tags: pandas, dask

I'd like to create a cartersian product of several arrays. For example, in Pandas:

```
a1 = np.arange(0,30.)
a2 = np.arange(0,30.)
a3 = np.arange(0,30.)
a4 = np.arange(0,30.)
a5 = np.arange(0,30.)

df = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a1,a2,a3,a4,a5]).to_frame(index=False)
```

If I add one more array (a6), then I start to run out of memory. Thus, I would like to do this in Dask:

```
p = itertools.product(*(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5))
da = dd.from_array(np.array(list(p)), chunksize=50000, columns=[0,1,2,3,4])
```

However, the above still uses a large amount of memory because of the conversion of the iterable to a list and then to a numpy array.  There must be a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: You are still converting `p` to a list, and then a `numpy` array.  You aren't chunking anything, as you do the entire conversion first

Comment: Yes, so the ideal situation would be able to create a dask array from an iterable (p in this case), without having to convert to a list first.